# loading event not working for the selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I can select the image element using jquery. the issue is I get errors when I try to trigger load event to track when loading the image is finshed. Here is the code and the result:

```
const coverSelector = $(`[aria-label="coverB"]`).find("image")[0];

  console.log(coverSelector);

  coverSelector.on("load", function() {
        alert('coverSelector is fully loaded!');
  });
```

[image]

I want to fire an event when the image is fully loaded. How can I do this?

Here is more of HTML code. I want to select `aria-label="coverB"` and the first image of it.

```html
<div class="slide-object slide-object-vectorshape shown      tweenable " style="z-index: 3; width: 1445px; height: 756px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 715.5px 371.5px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1405, -10); will-change: unset;" aria-label="coverB" data-model-id="65qtdJtdfsW" data-model-abs-id="_player.5g5VJPvQEXE.6hc3eOukv2x.65qtdJtdfsW" tabindex="-1" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256">
   <div class="slideobject-maskable" style="height:765px;width:1454px;transform:translate(-9px, -9px);" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-xmlns-xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="762" width="1451" viewBox="-9 -9 1451 762" data-commandset-id="2" data-accepts="events" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299.$0">
         <g class="eventable" data-accepts="events" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299.$0.$0">
            <image transform="scale(1, 1)" id="uniqueDomId-301" data-original-image="01" x="-6" y="-6" opacity="1" xlink:href="/H:/test%20covers/Untitled1%20-%20Storyline%20output/mobile/txt__default_65qtdJtdfsW.png" height="756" width="1445" data-accepts="events" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299.$0.$0.$0"></image>
         </g>
      </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML please instead of an image.

Comment: When you use `[0]` you're essentially selecting the raw HTLM element which doesn't have `on` as part of it's API. try `eq(0)` if jQuery still have that.

Comment: using eq I get the element like this and the error is gone but it dosen't fire the load event yet: `init [image#uniqueDomId-301, prevObject: init(1), context: document]
0: image#uniqueDomId-301
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: init [image#uniqueDomId-301, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[aria-label="coverB"] image"]
__proto__: Object(0)`

Comment: do you have the " coverSelector.on("load", function() {... " in a $(document ).ready() {} function? If not you might be defining the js before "$(`[aria-label="coverB"]`)" exists.

Comment: Good comment I'll try that ....